# Error in dynamically loaded user controls that reference other controls in different directories

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have the following scenario:

My directory structure is:

- ./Pages/Page.aspx
- ./RedControls/RedControl.ascx
- ./BlueControls/BlueControl.ascx

Page.aspx.cs dynamically creates RedControl:

```
RedControls_RedControl C = (RedControls_RedControl)Page.LoadControl("~/RedControls/RedControl.ascx");
```

RedControl.ascx uses BlueControl:

```
<uc:BlueControl runat="server" ID="ctrControl" />
```

This works great in development mode, however when I deploy it, I get:

**Exception type - HttpParseException - The base class includes the field 'ctrControl', but its type (BlueControls_BlueControl) is not compatible with the type of control (ASP.BlueControls_BlueControl_ascx).**

If I move RedControl and BlueControl in the same directory, then it works fine when deployed.

How can I get this to work without having to move files into a single directory (we have too many instances of this).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there perhaps old versions of ASCX or DLL files deployed?  The fact that it says the type is not compatible indicates to me that it's loading the type from an unexpected source.

Comment: No, there are no older versions deployed.  Fresh install.

Comment: did you try using ".." instead of "~" such as" LoadControl("../RedControls/RedControl.ascx");

Comment: Akhil - that did not resolve the issue.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Are you using IIS for development?

Comment: Interesting, ASP.BlueControls_BlueControl_ascx is the dynamically generated type, but BlueControls_BlueControl is being referred to, most likely because that is your tag reference... that seems strange why that would be.

Comment: What happens when you change the tag name to "asp"? Which version of asp.net are you using? Some threads out there that I just found reporting similar suggest that this could be a bug in asp.net, and how it's been fixed (somehow) in 3.5 (although 3.5 is .NET extension, so, this doesn't make a lot of sense to me). Maybe I should have asked for the web project's target version instead?

Answer (score 3):

This could happen in some scenarios where you have multiple folders that have controls that point to each other in both directions (or in more complex situations involving more folders).

The good news is that there is a simple way to solve it: turn off batching by setting batch="false" in the `<compilation>` section in web.config.

Comment: That is only a viable solution for small projects.  It is not recommended for larger deployments.  Looking for a definite fix, not a band-aid.

Comment: Actually, that is not the case. We have in some cases suggested this technique to customers with very large solutions and they had good success. The first thing you should try here is check whether doing this in fact solves the problem. If it does, then you can look at the memory usage to check whether it makes a measurable difference.